# Python script not executing after setting executable permission

Tags: python

i am having a python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

in top of my script? following is the permission i had set

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user1 user2 6423 Nov 15 15:12 test
```

i tried executing the script as user1 `./test` its giving me permission denied?

when i do

`whoami` it shows user1 and umask is 0022, user1 has bash as his default shell

`$python test` (it works fine)

Any ideas??

Comment: Are you running this on a volume with the mount option ``noexec``?

Comment: @gertvfijk No if that is the case the script wont execute when i try python script name.

Comment: Untrue. ``# ./testscript.py
-su: ./testscript.py: Permission denied`` and 
``# python testscript.py 
bla``

Answer (score 1):

I remember an issue like that because I had a test.pyc in the same directory, and interpreter was using it instead of the original interpreted one (test.py).
Maybe it's a lead for you.

Comment: thanks, but my org script name is different, for posting in the forum i used test script name is fsetup :-(

Answer (score 0):

When you mention `#!/usr/bin/env python` in first line, it looks for python from `$PATH`.

Type `which python` and check whether the path from the output is added to `$PATH`. If not add it.

- `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"`

For more information about setting the PATH variable refer this [page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_environment.htm)

Comment: i am having another script that is set up with same path to python interpretor, that will execute fine with ./script2 but the errror only happens to test script, i dont know what the problem is..is there anything other that PATH i need to look into

Comment: No. When you say the other scripts work fine with the same setup. I don't think the problem is with $PATH

Answer (score 0):

I *never* **ever** use names as `test` as my scriptname. Likewise for simple names as `time`, `date`, `parser`, etc unless in a package with absolute imports, and even then it's bad practice. These names are too likely to interfere with either installed modules or other scripts/packages in your working directory and/or path.

Conclusion: check if you don't have a folder called `test` in the same directory.

Comment: test is the name that i had use to post in the form the script name is different it is fsetup